# Как удалить кнопку <Добавить в корзину> на сайте WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как удалить кнопку <Добавить в корзину> везде на сайте WordPress ???

пробывал в Внешний вид ===> редактор тем ===> functions.php вставлять код:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_edd_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

также этот код добовлял в    Снипеты ===> Добавить новый....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не чего не помогает кнопка не проподает что делать?

Вот сайт:

https://pumpini.ru/

Comment: вы пробовали редактировать это в теме или в Виджетах?

Comment: Да конечно пробывал, только там нет функции чтобы убрать эту кнопку.

Comment: ВП не причём. Задавай вопросы производителю твоей коммерческой темы. Была бы тема из оф репо - можно было бы глянуть, а так - увы. И да. Никогда не лезь в файлы темы. Для кастомизации существует механизм дочерних тем.

Comment: спасибо за ответ)

Comment: вылезла теперь эта ошибка, вроде не чего не делал:

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/u1218989/data/www/pumpini.ru/wp-content/themes/foodz/includes/customize/ip_customize_settings.php on line 3975

Comment: в чем может быть проблема? гуглю результата 00000

Comment: @РобинГут из ошибки можно сделать вывод что в `foreach()` для перебора в переменной спользуется тип данных отличный от объекта или массива, либо не инициализированная переменная.